# What will be the area of the shaded portion?

Tags: geometry, circles

The diagram given is a square in which two quarter circle with radius $10\mathrm{cm}$ and a circle touching midpoints of all sides of square with radius $5\mathrm{cm}$. The question is to solve area of shaded portion only using elementary geometry.**No Trigonometry or calculus**
[image]

Comment: Beautiful question, will try it soon.

Comment: What have you tried? It helps to show your effort so that others don't have to repeat the same work. Regarding the question, the square seems useless. It adds no new information to the problem, other than giving a point of reference for the circles.

Comment: Is solving quadratic equations allowed? @MohammadAbdullah

Comment: @Mohammad Abdullah, are you testing our intelligence or want solution of this problem? However, show your work in order to get any response.

Comment: Also consider [Lune of Hippocrates (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_of_Hippocrates). @MohammadAbdullah

Comment: I have solved the question. If you want to see the solution, show us what you have tried so far.